# Sending Windows messages to another computer

Tags: delphi, windows-messages

I often use PostMessage in my Delphi programs to send messages between forms but I have been asked if I could make it possible to have a program running on a server doing some of the data manipulation instead of on the users computer to speed things up.
In order to do this I think the easiest way must be to send a Windows message to the program on the server telling it to do something. 
I have been looking around the internet but haven't found something that really helps me. A lot about the net send, but that won't help.

So my question is: Is it at all possible to send a Windows message to a program running on another computer (Knowing the IP) and where can I read about it?

Comment: If you already have a server, I recommend Indy with TIdHTTPServer, it is included with Delphi and frequently updated

Comment: Is the data manipulation on your server in a DBMS on it?  And which Delphi version?

Comment: The server is running MS SQL 2014 and I am using Delphi XE8 at the moment

Answer (score 2):

Windows messages cannot be sent to recipients on a different machine. They are delivered to windows on the local machine. In fact, they cannot be sent to windows in a different session on the same machine.

You need to look for a different form of communication. Something based on sockets, TCP/IP and so on is what is needed.

Comment: OK - then I will have to look for another solution.  I know that MS Navision sends messages from the client to the ApplicationServer using messagequeue (I remember since messagequeue wasn't installed as default on either Win 2K or XP as we used when I was working with that system)  so that may be something I should be investigating

Answer (score 2):

If your client computers are on the same LAN as the server, you might seriously consider moving your data manipulation into a DataSnap server written in Delphi.

Delphi comes with all the wherewithal you need for client machines to interact with a DataSnap server without having to get near Indy or having to re-invent the wheel to devise some kind of client-server protocol for the clients and server to interact.

Despite the impression the name might give, DataSnap doesn't *have* to involve a DBMS on the server, though it can easily do so.